# How to insert Ionic elements in InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am trying to insert Ionic elements such as buttons in the DOM of an InAppBrowser plugin. While I am able to add standard HTML tags, e.g. 'div' and 'p', to the browser window, it does not detect Ionic tags like 'ion-header'. How do I solve this issue ?

Also, I am currently using executeScript() method provided by InAppBrowserObject to insert HTML components.

Comment: include ionic cdn first then ionic tags will work.

Comment: I have included Ionic in the application and integrated it with Cordova. I have also installed the dependencies for InAppBrowser plugin required by both frameworks. Do you mean I should include the CDN in the script that I pass to the browser window ?

Comment: yes, because the website you are opening in in app browser dont have ionic so you cant style that website without using ionic. include ionic cdn in your `executeScript()` and try.

Comment: I tried inserting the Ionic CDN but get CORS policy error when the browser tries to access the src links in the CDN HTML.